# MYSQL insert with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How do i go about inserting a foreign key during insertion that references the relationship to another table.

I am trying to insert the CD 'duck' with an existing band in the band table.

`INSERT INTO CD (TITLE, YEAR) VALUES ('Ducks', 2013);`

My application is in Java and has 2 classes:

```
 Band class:
    String name
    int year
    ArrayList<String> members

 CD class:
    String title
    int year
```

SQL tables

```
CREATE TABLE BAND 
(
   BAND_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   NAME VARCHAR(50),
   YEAR INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(BAND_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE CD
(
   CD_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   TITLE VARCHAR(50),
   YEAR INT,
   B_ID INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(CD_ID),
   FOREIGN KEY(B_ID) REFERENCES BAND(BAND_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE MEMBER
(
   MEMBER_ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   NAME VARCHAR(50),
   B_ID INT,
   PRIMARY KEY(MEMBER_ID),
   FOREIGN KEY(B_ID) REFERENCES BAND(BAND_ID)
);
```

Comment: can you clarify what are you trying to do? insert a CD with non-existent band?

Comment: insert a CD with an existing band, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like this:

```
INSERT INTO CD (TITLE, YEAR, B_ID) VALUES ('Ducks', 2013, THEBANDID);
```

but the B_ID you want to use has to exist in the table Bands. So you can check on that before you do the insert

```
SELECT * FROM BAND WHERE BAND_ID = THEBANDID
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as reading your question, I think your Java Class `CD` lack relationship with class `BAND` (relating it with your database tables).

The `CD` class should have the `BandId` or `BandName` property, though I strongly suggest to add the `BandId`:

```
CD:
    String title
    int year
    int bandId
```

When inserting `CD` records to your database, you won't have any problems with foreign key constraints anymore, and use [STORED PROCEDURES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-routines.html).

`INSERT INTO CD (TITLE, YEAR, B_ID) VALUES (Param1, Param2, Param3);`